# Expand JSON data onclick

Tags: jquery, html, json

How to expand JSON data on click by id? I got stack with my code, once the button clicked all data expanded, what I want to do is only expanded one data based on an ID I clicked, here my fiddle right now
https://jsfiddle.net/zeef/2638rgtz/1/

With is code:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
          $('button').toggleClass('active');
          $('.title').toggleClass('active');
          $('nav').toggleClass('active');
        }
</script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div id="entrydata" class="profile">


</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "expand JSON data"? There's no JSON in your code.

Comment: The AJAX request in the fiddle is being blocked by CORS. You're not getting the JSON data in the first place.

Comment: You should use DOM navigation relative to `$(this)` to only expand the elements related to the button you click.

Comment: Thanks for all response, @Barmar where should I put this element? Is on myfunction for onclick? I am really new with JSon actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DOM navigation relative to the element.

Change your element so it passes `this` to the function:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(this)">
```

Then use that in the function:

```
function myFunction(element) {
    $(element).closest(".content").find("button, .title, nav").toggleClass("active");
});
```